# how can i load default country,state&City in the dependent dropdown in the page loading itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my asp.net mvc4 application,I have 3 dependent dropdowns named as country, state and city.I want to load the default values for country,state and city dropdowns as USA, Pennsylvania and Bethlehem in the page load it self.These country,state and cities are fetching from database.please suggest me appropriate jquery and ajax calling methods.Iam using this dropdowns in asp.net mvc4 application.

Comment: easy add `selected` attribute to those option in your select dropdown.. :):)

Answer (score 1):

**Dependent Dropdown Using AJAX**

```
function editData(ele) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("SingaleRecordClsss", "Class")',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'id': ele }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                $("#hdfid").val(ele);
                $("#ddacademy").val(result.classrecord.cacademyname);
                var id = result.classrecord.cacademyname;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("FillTeacherNameAccordingAcademy", "Teacher")',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ 'id': id }),
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (results) {

                            $("#ddteacher").find("option").remove();
                            $("#ddteacher").append("<option value='0'>--Select--</option>");
                            $.each(results.teacherlist, function (i, item) {
                                $("#ddteacher").append("<option value='" + item.sid + "'>" + item.sname + "</option>");
                            });
                            $("#ddteacher").val(result.classrecord.cteachername);
                            $("#ddstanedrd").val(result.classrecord.cstanderd);
                            $("#txtclassname").val(result.classrecord.classname);
                            $("#txtdatetime").val(result.classrecord.cdatetime);
                        }
                    });
                    $("#btnsubmit").html("Update");
                }
            });
      }
```